# How to add columns with space in their name in sas

Tags: sql, sas

I have a value which is sum of product sales
I want to add a column such as
Sum(product_sales ) as **Product  sales**
There is a column called product_sales from the table 1 and also add a column PRoduct NAme
There are no columns name product sales and product name I want to create them so that they are in the output :

Such that the output is :
Product name.     Product sales
Bat                          10
Ball                          30
Please help me how to create the above output .
Iam unsure on how to create columns with space in sas

Comment: Why would you want to use those as the NAME of the variable? You could put the specialized text in the LABEL of the variable. Then it will be easy to have those values displayed on reports without forcing the programmer to have to deal with goofy variable names.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want to assign a [LABEL](https://documentation.sas.com/?cdcId=pgmsascdc&cdcVersion=9.4_3.5&docsetId=lestmtsref&docsetTarget=n1r8ub0jx34xfsn1ppcjfe0u16pc.htm&locale=en) to your new variable.

```
proc sql;
  create table want as 
    select product_name label='Product Name'
         , sum(product_sales) as product_sales label='Product Sales'
    from have
    group by product_name
  ;
quit;
proc print data=want label;
run;
```